# Is it possible to install GRUB on a 2006 MacBook with 32bit EFI so I can also boot cleanly from 64bit OS Ubuntu server?

Tags: ubuntu, 64-bit, grub, 32-bit, efi

The machine is working, after many tries and big effort, it is up and running.

But to boot up the machine, I need to run a Linux Mint 18 boot disc, and tell the machine to boot from internal hard drive.

I've never been that knowledgeable on configuring GRUB. So I don't know where to start.

So the question is: How am I supposed to install a 32bit grub bootloader, running a 64bit OS, to get rid of the boot disc?

Comment: You mat want to try rEFInd ;)

Comment: Any solution would be welcome.. can  U suggest me any guide, specific for my case (32bit efi boot, 64bit os)?

Comment: http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/ Should work for any EFI implementation. At some point your specific case is addressed: *Most Intel-based Macs have 64-bit EFIs, so you should use the refind_x64.efi file with them; but very early Intel-based Macs have 32-bit EFIs (and sometimes 32-bit CPUs), which require the refind_ia32.efi file.*

Comment: 32 or 64-bit capable for a Macbook 2006 depends on the *specific* model designation, 'early', 32-bit or 'late', 64-bit.

Comment: I've already made all of the relevant researches, and this model is 64bit capable regarding the os, but 32bit capable regarding efi

Answer (score 0):

Use the rEFind script to get rid of the native Mac bootloader headaches. There's a little script kicking around which converts 64bit ISOs into 32bit bootloader ISOs for these old Macs. I can confirm that it doesn't work for me in M1 Macs, however. It works fine on an old Intel Mac running Yosemite.